# Same person as supervisor/co-promotor and professor/promotor

Tags: phd, supervision

I've just started a PhD. Currently I only have one person who is supervising me (the professor). So he is now both my supervisor *and* my promotor.

Now other (ex) PhD students are telling me that these roles should be filled by different people, to prevent mix of interests. But I don't have sufficient insight on what they are referring to.

Should I be worried? Should I talk to my department head to change the situation?

**edit,** let me clarify:

- With "promotor" I mean the main project supervisor, being a professor. He has the final responsibility.
- With "supervisor" I mean the *daily* supervisor, sometimes also called co-promotor. To my understanding this is often somebody else, for instance an associate professor or assistant professor.

Comment: Could you explain what a promoter is? I have never heard of that in this context.

Comment: To the OP, by promotor do you mean  _a full professor of a Dutch, Flanders, or German university who formally promotes a PhD candidate to doctor, and is (formally) the principal supervisor during the doctoral research._ as the [Promoter Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promoter) says?

Comment: @scaaahu Yes. Sorry, I thought these were common terms. Are they clear now?

Answer (score 2):

Considering German institution/university where I am doing my Ph.D. now, you are the person who is responsible for finding a second supervisor to your thesis.

- Regulations for Doctoral Degree Studies in Germany says (computer science field):

§ 3 and § 4 § 3 II (Primary Supervisors):
“Professors and lecturers who have completed their post-doctoral qualifications, are members of the faculty, or were included in the acceptance of the dissertation, can be primary supervisors.”

§ 4 II (Secondary Supervisors):
“Secondary supervisors assume a supervisory and consultative function. Professors and university lecturers with post-doctoral qualifications can serve as secondary supervisors. The Doctoral Committee can authorize additional scholars and scientists to serve as secondary dissertation supervisors upon case-by-case assessment and the issuance of a resolution to that effect. They need not belong to the faculty.”

Comment: Interesting! So in Germany your "promotor" can also be a post-doc? I thought it always had to be a professor.. But back to my question: when I discussed the issue with my professor, he suggested that I did not need a secondary supervisor. Is he overestimating himself?